# JAVA OCR to txt file

Tags: java, ocr

Good afternoon people,

With the help of research I did the code below to read texts of images:

```
package pckLeitor;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;

public class Tess4jOCRv2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TesseractException {

        File repository = new File("C:\\Users\\RAFSOUZA\\Desktop\\OCRTest");

        try
        {
            for (File file : repository.listFiles()) {

                String dtNow = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
                tesseract.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\RAFSOUZA\\Desktop\\Rafa3lOneiL\\BibliotecasExternasJAVA\\TesseractORC\\");
                String fullText = tesseract.doOCR(file);

                String fileExit = "C:\\Users\\RAFSOUZA\\Desktop\\OCRTest" + dtNow + ".txt";

                FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fileExit);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

                out.write(fullText);
                out.newLine();
                out.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Ocorreu o seguinte erro" + e);
        }

    }

}
```

I would like to improve this code for:

1) Read all images in a folder

2) Generate a txt file with the data read from each image

Can you give me a direction?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so you've already gotten the code to read an image and output all text, right?

Let's try and wrap that with a loop or something using [`File#listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles) and we should be ok!
Something like this should work, note I wrote this in notepad and it has not been tested!

```
import java.io.File;

public class Tess4jOCR {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TesseractException {
        File repository = new File("C:\\Users\\RAFSOUZA\\Desktop\\OCRTest");

        try {
            for (File file : repository.listFiles()) {
                String dtNow = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
                tesseract.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\RAFSOUZA\\Desktop\\Rafa3lOneiL\\BibliotecasExternasJAVA\\TesseractORC\\");
                String fullText = tesseract.doOCR(file);

                //String file = "O:\\Operações\\MIS\\Csa_OCR" + dtNow + ".txt";
                String file = "C:\\RegistroRS" + dtNow + ".txt";

                FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                //System.out.println(fullText);

                out.write(fullText);
                out.newLine();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ocorreu o seguinte erro" + e);
        }

    }

}
```

Simply put all images you want to process in `C:\\Users\\RAFSOUZA\\Desktop\\OCRTest` (or whatever directory the `repository` variable is set to, and run it and it should output it to `C:\\RegistroRS-<timestamp>.txt`

Please note you may want to add additional logic to check filenames or maybe output the txt file in a name that's related to the original input so you don't reprocess things if you run the code more than once and you can easily tell which output came from which input.

Comment: The code executes normal, when I send the contents of the variable fullText with a system.out.printLn () I notice that the reading is working correctly however it does not generate any txt file and there is nothing in the Catch Block. I launched the new code in Thead

Comment: Maybe your code for the thread doesn't write the file specifically after the text file is populated? hard to know without seeing your code.